# Iframe fetching the full screen method from iframe source

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I try to create a one liner iframe that users can add in their sites and this iframe adress is my site.
My problem is that if i want it to be able to become full screen i need to supply them with js code and i don't want it i want it to fetch the js code from my site.

The js that i use to make full screen when needed is :

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);

    function receiveMessage(evt) {
        if (evt.origin === 'site src') {
            //if (isNaN(evt.data)) return;
            var iframe = document.getElementById('someId');
            if (event.data.height !== 0) {
                iframe.height = 100 + "%";
                iframe.width = 100 + "%";
                iframe.style.position = 'fixed';
                iframe.style.top = '2%';
                iframe.style.left = '2%';

            }
            else {
                iframe.height = 110 + "px";
                iframe.width = 300 + "px";
                iframe.style.position = 'relative';

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This script currently written at the client the one that use the iframe.
The iframe looks like.

```
<iframe id="expertips_iframe" src="my site adress" width="300px" height="110px" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I want the iframe line to fetch the js code from my site and inject it to the user/client that use the iframe, or any other way as long as i do it (the iframe and the js) in one line.

Hope it is clear enough and thank you.

Comment: Why is this question tagged under angularjs?

Comment: Oh i forget to add that iframe will become full screen when it get event from source site (my site)

Comment: My bad Alon, wrong tag.

Comment: Does  the `src="my site adress"` in your  iframe element has a url of the same domain, because you can't just manipulate content from different domains like that (Due to security restrictions)

Comment: It is not at the same domains and currently at that way it does work.

Comment: I mean if i put the script in the html where i put the iframe screen become full when it get the event from my site (which had totally different domain. If you have/know a better way i am open for suggestion.

Comment: I don't think iframe wil work, you can give them a path to a js on your server, and then you'll have access directly to the page. You can also instruct them to include a `div` with specific ID that your script will manipulate its content